# Billing Database

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012

I have created 2 tables @ CustomerHistory and @ CustomerPaymentHistory
here is the sql syntax

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerHistory]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [HistoryID] AS ('CLI'+right('000000000'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID]),(5))) PERSISTED NOT NULL, 
    [CustomerID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [InvoiceNumber] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    [InvoiceDate] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    [InvoiceTotal] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    [Balance] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMERHISTORY] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [CustomerID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CUSTOMER_CH]  
        FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([ID])
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerPaymentHistory]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PaymentID] AS ('CLI'+right('000000000'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID]),(5))) PERSISTED NOT NULL, 
    [HistoryID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [PaymentDate] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    [PaymentAmount] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    [BalanceDue] NVARCHAR(20) NULL, 
    [PaidInFull] BIT NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMERPAYMENTHISTORY] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [HistoryID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CUSTOMERHISTORY_CPH] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([HistoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CustomerHistory] ([ID])
)
```

but when i'm trying to update the table, I get an error:

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.
>   Please correct the following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[CustomerHistory]' contains no
>   primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in
>   the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it
>   should be persisted.

How can fix this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to add some key which already not exist in [dbo].[Customers]?

Comment: Actually you need to add the `CustomerID` to the Foreign Key in the `CustomerPaymentHistory` table. That's part of the PK in the `CustomerHistory` Table.

Comment: I think you might also want to look at your datatypes. Storing Balance and other monetary values as varchar is a very bad decision. You need to be able to use those as calculations and storing them as varchar means you have to first convert it to numeric datatype and hope you don't have invalid characters in there. Make it easy on yourself and use the proper datatypes.

Comment: Can you please post your update query?